# ImagePicker dismiss to black screen after picking image in an Angular 6 microapp

Tags: ios, swift, angular, swift4, angular6

I have an application that loads a microapp on a webview coded in Angular 6.
This microapp has a button to upload a photo with the following action:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="hidden" (change)="readInputImage($event)">
```

It will show an action sheet that let's the user choose to upload from camera or from photo library.
After finishing to pick an image, the picker will dismiss and only shows black screen.

Is there a way for me to access the `imagepicker` so that I can change the `modalpresentationstyle`? (because I suspect that the presentation style should be *overFullScreen*

Or is there any other solution you guys know regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this on your class with the webview? 
It will detect if the next vc is **UIImagePickerController** and will override its **modalPresentationStyle**

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
   if viewControllerToPresent is UIImagePickerController {
     viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
   }

   super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm. but it's weird that the webview's navigation destroys my applications navigation where dismissing a presented VC gave my app black screen.